# Build array on every full paragraph tag

Tags: php, split, implode

I am trying to build an array value of every item in my string that has `<p>` tags around it (opening and closing ofcourse).

What I have now:

```
$info = $contentcr[0]['fulltext'];
preg_match_all('%^(<p[^>]*>.*?</p>)$%im', $info, $infoarray);
$splitinfo = preg_split('%^(<p[^>]*>.*?</p>)$%im', $info, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

When I print `$splitinfo` somehow this is my array:

```
Array ( [0] =>
Afdeling: Bla & Bla

Locatie: ‘Stadhuis Rotterdam’ – Coolsingel 40 Rotterdam

Klant: Ontwikkelings

[1] =>
Bedrijf: Rotterdam Datum April 2013

[2] => )
```

This is what my string (`$info`) looks like:

```
<p>Afdeling: Bla &amp; Bla </p>
<p>Locatie: ‘Stadhuis Rotterdam’ – Coolsingel 40 Rotterdam</p>
<p>Klant: Ontwikkelings</p>
<p>Bedrijf: Rotterdam Datum April 2013</p>
```

How can I create every single paragraph as individual array values?

Answer (score 0):

Using the following regex:

```
preg_match_all('@<p[^>]*>(.*?)</p>@im', $info, $infoarray);
```

it will match any `<p></p>` and select the inner content (non-greedy using `(.*?)`). `preg_match_all` writes all findings into a multi-dimensional array. The first index will contain complete matches, while the `2..N` will contain a list of groups that matched. In our case something like:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "<p>adf</p>"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "<p>xy</p>"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "adf"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "xy"
  }
}
```

will be generated. We can now just select the second part:

```
if (count($infoarray) > 1) {
  // yes we found paragraphs!
  $paragraphs = $infoarray[1];
}
```

There is no need for an additional split.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below

```
$info = $contentcr[0]['fulltext'];
$splitinfo = preg_split('/(<\s*p\s*\/?>)|(<\s*br\s*\/?>)|(\s\s+)|(<\s*\/p\s*\/?>)/', $info, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: If you need it to contain the <P> tags use 
`$splitinfo = preg_split('~(</?p>\s*)+~', $info, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

Comment: Thanks, but this stores all values in a single array value. Not every paragraph line as a new value